# phpbb forum files deleted but database safe. how to configure new files with the existing database?

Tags: phpbb, phpbb3

I have been using a phpbb forum.

It got deleted.

The database is intact. safe.

What are all the files i should modify.

I hope it is mostly one config file.

what are all the configurations i need to change?

so that the new files will work with the existing database.

I forgot the version. may be i can read it from the database.

Anyway... I need a help to restore my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the answer from phpbb forum.

it worked.

Here it is...

http://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=2110940&p=12899021#p12899021

:D

but still if people would like to comment or suggest then please do so.

Answer (score 2):

If you have no files at all, the easiest way is to:

1 - download your database

**2** - Create a new installation of Phpbb (easiest to use the same version you used to run)

**3** - Once you have a new bare bones forum, log into Phpmyadmin, or whatever you use to manage databases, and drop all the tables from the new install, leaving a completely empty db.

**4** - Import your saved DB to the empty database. This will restore all users and posts etc

**5** - If your old forum used any mods you can either reinstall them (any db tables should still be there), or use the Support Toolkit (download from phpBB) and run the database cleaner. This will remove all non standard tables leaving your db as if it was a clean install but retaining all posts, users etc.

When I lost all my forums, I chose this route and cleaned the database.  I then updated the forum to the latest version, and reinstalled all styles and mods from scratch.  It's probably not the easiest way to do things, but I knew I had everything bug free, up to date, and no bits of unused mod cluttering the database.

Answer (score 2):

First, you'll need the DB URL, (localhost) DB name,the user name and password for the database and the prefix for the tables. config example:

```
<?php
// phpBB 3.0.x auto-generated configuration file
// Do not change anything in this file!
$dbms = 'mysqli';
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbport = '';
$dbname = 'name_of_phpbb_db';
$dbuser = 'your_mysql_username';
$dbpasswd = 'your_mysql_pass';
$table_prefix = 'phpbb_';
$acm_type = 'file';
$load_extensions = '';

@define('PHPBB_INSTALLED', true);
// @define('DEBUG', true);
// @define('DEBUG_EXTRA', true);
```

Then you can delete or rename the install folder and go directly to your site. You'll have to tweak the DB in phpMyAdmin if you had a style other than default. and being your phpBB directory was gutted, all attachments, images, mod's and styles will be gone. You'll have to go into the modules_table in the DB and disable the non existent mods or you'll get errors in the ACP